# Manual scaling of axis (poltting with boxes) in gnuplot

Tags: linux, graph, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a really long list, which represents frequency of some data. The x axis goes from 1 to 1881, and the y goes from 1 to 1978. I tried plotting with the following configurations:

```
set log y 5
set log x 32
set xtics 2
set ytics 5
plot "freq.dat" w boxes
```

But i get the following result:
[image]

Which is clearly not good because there are these intersections of the boxes. I want to have some kind of scale that have a lot more space between 10 and 150 than the outside of this area. How can i do that? I've tried every combination of logs and xtics and couldn't make it look good. The y axis seems good to me, the only problem is the spacing of x-axis.
Also, i want to know how to do this in gnuplot specifically (if possible).
Thanks.

Comment: could you upload sample data somewhere for testing? otherwise, it's hard to tell what might look "good" in this particular case...

Comment: Yes. Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByYVc0EcZ_CFdldSbGl0N0ZQQ2s/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your script overrides somewhere the default `boxwidth`. The default behavior is:

> By default, adjacent boxes are extended in width until they touch
>   each other.  A different default width may be specified using the `set boxwidth` command. `Relative` widths are interpreted as being a
>   fraction of this default width.

So for example this:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output 'fig.png'

set log x 2
set log y 5

set yr [0.2:3125]
set xr [1:512]

set boxwidth 1 relative

set xtics 1,2,512 out nomirror
set ytics 1,5,3125 out nomirror

unset key

#set style fill pattern 6
plot 'freq.dat' w boxes lc rgb 'royalblue' lw 1.1
```

then yields:
[image]

Comment: Great! But can i let them spaced, using this configuration for boxwidths? Thanks.

Comment: @Dovah-king you could experiment with the relative width, for example `set boxwidth 0.1 relative` doesn't look that bad (it will keep the width adaptive but also leave room in between)